# Error: Method not found: 'NullThrownError' in flutter

Tags: android, flutter, build-runner, flutter-upgrade

I was getting the below error while running the flutter application post flutter upgrade to 3.10.6

```
Failed to build build_runner:build_runner:
/C:/Users/Admin/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/build_runner-2.3.2/lib/src/build_script_generate/bootstrap.dart:76:40: Error: Method not found: 'NullThrownE
rror'.
      final error = e[0] as Object? ?? NullThrownError();
                                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Answer (score 7):

For me this happen because the incompatibility of each package used. I think the packages that relate to build runner are floor_generator and retrofit_generator. You can simply resolve the issue by following these:

- remove `retrofit_generator`, `floor_generator` and `build_runner` from dev_dependencies
- add packages from terminal -> `flutter pub add dev:build_runner`, `flutter pub add dev:floor_generator` and `flutter pub add dev:retrofit_generator`
- try to build the build_runner again -> `dart run build_runner build`

or if the error still occur try this package version:

- dependencies: floor: ^1.4.2 retrofit: ^3.0.1
- dev_dependencies: build_runner: ^2.4.6 retrofit_generator: ^4.2.0 floor_generator: ^1.4.2

Comment: Thank you @AliMahfud! it helped me with your first solution. <3

Answer (score 3):

Resolved issue by upgrading build_runner dependency

**Steps:**

1. Open Project in Android Studio
2. Navigate to Terminal Tab in Android Studio
3. Execute the below command

   $ flutter clean

   $ flutter pub get

   $ flutter pub upgrade

   $ flutter pub run build_runner build --delete-conflicting-outputs
4. Run the application.

The above solution worked for me. Hope, it will help to others as well.

Answer (score 0):

I use flutter3.10.5 version, and I also encountered the same error when using build_runner. Confusing [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0MF9J.png)

Comment: ➜  untitled dart run build_runner build       
Building package executable... 
Failed to build build_runner:build_runner:
../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/build_runner-2.2.0/lib/src/build_script_generate/bootstrap.dart:76:40: Error: Method not found: 'NullThrownError'.
      final error = e[0] as Object? ?? NullThrownError();
                                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

Comment: I tried $ flutter pub run build_runner build --delete-conflicting-outputs command, kindly check with this if it may help you.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I have tried both $ flutter pub upgrade and $ flutter pub run build_runner build --delete-conflicting-outputs commands, but I still get the same error message as before.

Comment: i have same issue bad days

Comment: ```
pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/build_runner-2.2.0/lib/src/build_script_generate/bootstrap.dart:76:40: Error: Method not found: 'NullThrownError'.
      final error = e[0] as Object? ?? NullThrownError();
```

Comment: anyone resolved the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try dependecy follwing version in you pubspec.yaml file

retrofit_generator: ^7.0.8
build_runner: ^2.1.0

Comment: it should be comment not an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove build_runner-(*any version or variant) package/s in ***.../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev***

It works for me.

Comment: add more details!

Answer (score -1):

This what worked for me

- delete pubspec.lock
- `flutter pub cache clean`
- `flutter clean`
- `flutter upgrade` (probably optional)
- `flutter pub get`
- `flutter pub run build_runner build --delete-conflicting-outputs`